# Explain this backtracing

Tags: python-3.x, backtracking

I saw this code for backtracking on the internet and i am confused about some of it parts

```
a_string = 'abc'

def get_permutation(some_string, idx):
    if idx == 2:
        return ["".join(some_string)]

    permutations = []
    for j in range(idx, len(some_string)):
        words_list =some_string
        print("idx is ",idx)
        print("j is ",j)
        words_list[idx], words_list[j] = words_list[j], words_list[idx]
        print(words_list)
        print(permutations)
        permutations += get_permutation(words_list, idx + 1)
        print("a")


    return permutations

permutations = get_permutation(list(a_string), 0)
for perm in permutations:
     print(perm)
```

i added some print statements for debugging and i do not understand these things:

1. how does this not end the function and reduce the value of idx by 1

   ```
   return ["".join(some_string)]
   ```

2.how does this not add all the word_list in permutations and call the function recursively sometimes but not other

```
permutations += get_permutation(words_list, idx + 1)
```